# copy text from textfield with not enabling keyboard

Tags: ios, xcode4, uitextfield

i have a uitextfield and some text on it, i want to know how to create a code that my user touch the field and  can copy the txt to use for something else.
my uitextfiled.enable = no;
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the copying goes, you need to check out [the UIPasteboard Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html).  Using that class, you can put text onto the pasteboard very easily.

For not enabling the text field, you can simply leave it disabled, but capture the touch event anyway.

For the pasteboard, try going through [this tutorial](http://www.mobileorchard.com/new-in-iphone-30-tutorial-series-part-3-copy-paste-with-uipasteboard/).

Answer (score 0):

I you are able to use `UITextField` class instead you could set the `editable` property to `NO`. Selecting text will still be possible.

Comment: Yes, `UITextField` doesn't show the keyboard when you set `editiable=NO